# Image properties "dimensions" with "odd" unicode code points

Tags: windows, unicode, properties

I am poking around in the file properties for images, specifically jpg files created by a camera/scanner/adobe/etc.

There is one detail that is different than the rest.  The image dimensions seems to have a Unicode codepoint that doesn't appear in the displayed text.  The text appears as something like: `‪3264 x 2448`.

As it turns out, there are codepoints on either end of this string that I cannot figure out.  It is probably very straight forward, but after my searching I am at a loss.

The property documentation can be found here:

[System.Image.Dimensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787458.aspx)

```
    property format: {6444048F-4C8B-11D1-8B70-080036B11A03}
    0xd => 13 => property id (for Systems.Image.Dimensions)
    3264 x 2448 => Image dimensions as the "appear" on the screen
```

Here is what I have (Python 3.5 output):

```
    0xd => ‪3264 x 2448‬   0xd => b"?3264 x 2448?" len:  13
```

This is the actual string converted to hex bytes.

```
Hex Bytes: e2 80 aa 33 32 36 34 20 78 20 32 34 34 38 e2 80 ac
Character: ?? ?? ??  3  2  6  4     x     2  4  4  8 ?? ?? ??
```

Does anyone know what the "0xe280aa" and "0xe280ac" are and what I am missing?

They are the only "interesting" characters in the entire properties collection for a jpg image.  I don't know what they are, or why they are present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your property text is encoded in UTF-8.

`e2 80 aa` is the UTF-8 encoding of Unicode codepoint `U+202A LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING`.

`e2 80 ac` is the UTF-8 encoding of Unicode codepoint `U+202C POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING`.

These markers are used when embedding left-to-right text in bidirectional text.

Raymond Chen blogged about this in relation to a similar issue with filenames displayed in Windows Explorer:

[Why is there an invisible U+202A at the start of my file name?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150506-00/?p=44924)

Comment: I am quite unfamiliar with this area of Unicode and was having a difficult time even describing it.  Thank you for the information and the pointer.